# Learning python, stuck in gui program that won't run

Tags: python, user-interface, button, tkinter

I've been following a tutorial, and wrote this program. Could someone help me figure out why I'm getting the error message. "Application instance has no attribute 'text'"

```
from Tkinter import *

class Application(Frame):
    """ A GUI application with three buttons."""

    def __init__(self,master):
        """ This initialized the Frame"""
        Frame.__init__(self, master)
        self.grid()
        self.create_widgets()
        self.buttonclicks = 0

    def create_widgets(self):
        """Create a button that measures clicks."""
        #create first button
        self.button1 = Button(self, text = "Total Clicks: 0")
        self.button1.grid()

        self.instruction = Label(self, text= "Enters the password")
        self.instruction.grid(row=0, column=0, columnspan=2, sticky=W)

        self.password = Entry(self)
        self.password.grid(row=1,column=1, sticky=W)

        self.button1["command"] = self.update_count
        self.button1.grid(row=2,column=0,sticky=W)

        self.submit_button = Button(self, text="Submit", command=self.reveal())

        self.texts = Text(self, width=35, height=5,wrap=WORD)
        self.texts.grid(row=4,column=1,columnspan=2,sticky=W)

    def update_count(self):
        """Increase this click count and display the new total"""
        self.buttonclicks += 1
        self.button1["text"] = "Total Clicks: " + str(self.buttonclicks)

    def reveal(self):
        """Reveal the password"""
        content = self.password.get()

        messsage=""

        if content == "password":
            message = "You have access to the data."
        else:
            message = "Access denied."

        self.texts.insert(0.0,message)



root = Tk()

root.title("GUI test")
root.geometry("250x185")

app = Application(root)

root.mainloop()
```

The thing is I already have a textfield defined as 'texts', and if it can get password from the attributes, i see no reason it would not get the texts.

Edit: was asked for the error:

```
   Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "clickcounter.py", line 58, in <module>
    app = Application(root)
  File "clickcounter.py", line 10, in __init__
    self.create_widgets()
  File "clickcounter.py", line 28, in create_widgets
    self.submit_button = Button(self, text="Submit", command=self.reveal())
  File "clickcounter.py", line 49, in reveal
    self.texts.insert(0.0,message)
  AttributeError: Application instance has no attribute 'texts'
```

Comment: Can you include the stack-trace that gives you that error message? it makes it easier to look through your code.

Comment: As a general rule too, just to be a nit-pick try to avoid `*` glob imports in python. It is much clearer and easier to debug code if you explicitly import each thing (i.e. from `Tkinter import Text, Entry, Button, Label`) or  just do `import Tkinter` and call everything explicitly ie. `Tkinter.Text(...)`

Comment: Good tip. I added the error message to the original post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change line:

```
self.submit_button = Button(self, text="Submit", command=self.reveal())
```

to

```
self.submit_button = Button(self, text="Submit", command=self.reveal)
```

When you are passing it `self.reveal()` it is calling `self.reveal()` at that point, before `self.texts` is defined.

You want to pass it the function to call not the result of the function called.

Comment: Yes, that fixed it, thank you very much, I did not realize you could pass a function without calling it by not using parentheses. Glad I learned that!

Comment: Yes, in fact with Python most anything can be set like that. So for example you could say `foo = self.reveal`  and then later call `foo(...)`

Comment: @twoshoes In Python, basically *everything* is a [first class object](http://python-history.blogspot.nl/2009/02/first-class-everything.html). And in Python, what we call variables are actually more like "labels" hung on objects. The code `x=4` hangs the label `x` on the integer object `4`.